# python: Importing function with references to global scope

Tags: python, import, scope

I have two files `module.py` and `main.py`

In `module.py` I have a function which uses a constant defined outside of its scope.

```
#module.py
def add(x):
    s = x + const
    return s
if __name__ == '__main__':
    const = 2
    print(add(2))
```

It prints `4` as output when run directly.

In `main.py` I have:

```
#main.py
import module as m

const = 2
print(m.add(2))
```

It gives error: `NameError: name 'const' is not defined`

Is there a way to make m.add() look for `const` in `main.py` global scope? I'd like not to pass `const` to `add()` as a function variable.

Comment: Short answer: No, it’s not possible. You either have to make `const` a module member (e.g. `m.const = 2`), or pass it to the function.

Comment: What's your real use case? Why wouldn't you want to pass a value to a function? That is how functions are supposed to work.

Comment: I want to separate my model functions from simulation case. Some of those functions use same constants which i want to declare only once. Yet I'd like to have possibility to change them in simulation file. 

`m.const` does what i want

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706879/global-variable-with-imports/38899557?noredirect=1#comment78306834_38899557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your real use case is, but if you want to have a shared variable between modules you need to have that variable defined at module scope.

Declare it in one module:

```
#module.py
const = 0  # declare as global of module.py
def add(x):
    s = x + const
    return s
if __name__ == '__main__':
    const = 3
    print(add(2))
```

...and reference it in another:

```
#main.py
import module as m

m.const = 3  # reference module's variable 
print(m.add(2))
```