# Global variable with imports between 3 files

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

I come from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706879/global-variable-with-imports) that was helpful but not enough. My case is slightly different but most important is my situation: I'm refactoring a code of 1000+ lines (in one file) and so making a change in the name of something can quite quickly become painful.

So I've split my file into 3:

- settings.py in which I've defined all the global variables (there are
  a lot - mostly booleans and strings)
- synchro.py which can change
  their values
- groups.py which can also change them

I'll simplify the stuff here.

settings.py:

```
MY_VAR = "plane"
```

synchro.py:

```
from settings import *
import groups

def main():
  global MY_VAR
  MY_VAR = "boat"
  groups.update()
```

groups.py:

```
from settings import *

def update():
  print MY_VAR # will print "plane" instead of "boat"
```

I also tried to write `import settings` instead of `from settings import *` but in that case python tells me `global settings.MY_VAR` is an error, and it does not recognize `settings.MY_VAR` if I remove the `global` line.

So what can be the quickest/easiest way to get this work?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like below, its not so recommend to do `from settings import *` , it cause namespace pollution and make things harder to debug later.
i usually only use global within the same file though i try to minimize the global usage if possible

settings.py

```
MY_VAR = "plane"
```

synchro.py:

```
import settings
import groups

def main():
  # no need to declare global here, access trough settings namespace instead
  settings.MY_VAR = "boat"
  groups.update()
```

groups.py:

```
import settings

def update():
  print settings.MY_VAR # will print "plane" at first, after synchro main, MY_VAR should carry 'boat'
```