# How to import a folder with absolute path as package?

Tags: python

The path is `app/base/admin/crud/__init__.py`.

I want to import an entire folder as a package like this:

```
import app.base.admin.crud as cx
```

But it doesn't work and gives this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'app.base' has no attribute 'admin'
```

But when I import it's function like this `from app.base.admin.crud import crud`, it works.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have the top level (location of app dir) in your Python Path? You also need to have a __init__.py file in every subdirectory leading to your module, e.g. app/__init__.py, app/base/__init__.py

Comment: @StuartBuckingham Why do i have to have `__init__.py` inside each of them, i've done creating it for testing but didn't work either. I only have `__init__.py` inside app,admin and crud folder. I also made the test folder, all of sub folders don't have init file and it works  - don't know why it doesn't in the app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation about packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

More specifically that part:

> [...] when using syntax like import item.subitem.subsubitem, each item except for the last must be a package; the last item can be a module or a package but can’t be a class or function or variable defined in the previous item.

When using the `import x.y.z` statement alone (without `from`), you're actually importing a package for usage in your code as `x.y.z.something()`. Each part of that path must be a proper package (in other words, contain a `__init__.py` file)

Comment: Thank you, so it means there's no way to directly `import z` with given path? I want to use `z.something()`, not `x.y.z.something()` like `from app.base.admin.crud import __init__` ?

Comment: In that case, `z` must be a package and function `something()` must either be defined or imported inside `__init__.py`. You would use it like that: `from x.y import z` then in `__init__.py` inside `z` folder, you could either import `something` from a submodule, or define the function directly.